# Comparison on the basis of min function

Tags: python, python-2.7

How exactly does the min function work for lists in python ?

For example,

```
 num = [1,2,3,4,[1,2,3]]
 num2 = [1,2,3,4,5]

 min(num,num2)
```

gives `num2` as the result. Is the comparison value based or length based ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First thing - when comparing two lists with `min`, elements are compared in order.  So it is comparing `1` with `1`, `2` with `2`... and `5` with `[1,2,3]`.

Second, in python 2, unequal types are allowed to be compared, and give an "arbitrary, but consistent" ordering.  Quoth the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in):

> The operators <, >, ==, >=, <=, and != compare the values of two
>   objects. The objects need not have the same type. If both are numbers,
>   they are converted to a common type. Otherwise, objects of different
>   types always compare unequal, and are ordered consistently but
>   arbitrarily.
>
> ...
>
> (This unusual definition of comparison was used to simplify the
>   definition of operations like sorting and the in and not in operators.
>   In the future, the comparison rules for objects of different types are
>   likely to change.)

In cPython, at least, this comparison is equivalent to comparing the strings that represent their respective types.  Therefore:

```
5 < [1,2,3]
Out[8]: True
```

because `'int' < 'list'`.  I believe this is an implementation detail, the arbitrariness of this ordering should be stressed.

Thankfully in python 3 this silliness is replaced with `TypeError`.

Comment: That doc quote seems slightly misleading - I think it was right at some point in the past, but even in Python 2's case, it isn't the whole story anymore. What happens in all versions since 2.1 is that each object is given a chance to answer the comparison: `a < b` calls `a.__lt__(b)` (which can return True, False, or "NotImplemented", the clayton's answer). If it is NotImplemented (or the method doesn't exist), it tries `b.__ge__(a)`. Python 2 will then try `__cmp__`. After all that, if there's still no answer, *then* the default - comparison by type or TypeError is used.

Comment: @lvc yes, I cherry-picked sentences from the docs that were relevant to comparing two built-in types.  All of that information is essentially noise that isn't pertinent to understanding why `5 < [1,2,3]`.

Answer (score 1):

When you compare incompatible data types in python it compares the "first letter" of the data types. for Ex:

```
>>> {}<[]
True
'dict'<'list'
```

here **'d'<'l'**,hence returns True. The same logic is implemented in all the places wherever you have comparison like <,>,=, min(), max()...

I hope the above example is clear now.